# Looping the grid load to the Item that is used this.getStore (). Load ()

Tags: javascript, extjs

Why is looping of grid loading when I use this.getStore().isLoaded()?

And I also noticed that every value of index_record in me is -1, while I'm sure that store_ca contains a record with id == 1

```
    ...
{
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            text: 'Контрагент1',
            dataIndex: 'contragent',
            flex: 1,
            editor: combo,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                displayField:'name',
                valueField:'id',
                queryMode:'remote',
                store: Ext.data.StoreManager.get('ContrAgents'),

            },

            renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view){
                if(this.getStore().isLoaded()){
                    store_ca = Ext.data.StoreManager.get('ContrAgents');                        
                    index_record = store_ca.findExact('id', 1);
                    console.log(index_record)
                }
                if(index_record != -1){
                    rs = store_ca.getAt(index_record).data;
                    return rs.name;
                }
            }
        },
    ...
```

In store_ca Store "ContrAgents" is located.
This my Store "ContrAgents":

```
var urlRoot = 'data?model=Contragents&method=';
Ext.define('BookApp.store.ContrAgents', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'BookApp.model.ContrAgents',
    autoLoad: true,
    storeId: 'ContrAgents',
    proxy: {

            type: 'ajax',
            noCache: false,
            actionMethods: {update: 'GET',create: 'GET',destroy: 'GET'},
            api: {
                create:     urlRoot + 'Create',
                read:       urlRoot + 'Read',
                update:     urlRoot + 'Update',
                destroy:    urlRoot + 'Destroy'
            },
            reader: {

                type: 'json',
                metaProperty: 'meta',
                rootProperty: 'data',
                idProperty: 'id',
                totalProperty: 'meta.total',
                successProperty: 'meta.success'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json',
                encode: true,
                writeAllFields: true,
                rootProperty: 'data',
                allowSingle: false

            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this.getStore().isLoad()` to check store is loaded. If `this.getStore.load()` will reload the store. If it is an asynchronous load then your lookup fails as the store might not have loaded at that point of execution.

```
...
{
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        text: 'Contragents',
        dataIndex: 'contragent',
        editor: {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                allowBlank: false,
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'id',
                queryMode: 'remote',
                store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('ContrAgents')
                },
        renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view){                
                if(this.getStore().isLoaded()){
                    store_ca = Ext.data.StoreManager.get('ContrAgents');
                    //'ContrAgents' should be 'storeId' for the store 
                    // you are refering to and should be listed in 
                    //stores[] array of app.js 
                    index_record = store_ca.findExact('id', 1);

                }
                if(index_record != -1){
                    rs = store_ca.getAt(index_record).data;
                    return rs.name;
                }
            }
        },
...
```

Comment: 'this.getStore ().isLoad()' I need to use in renderer. Can you give an example?

Comment: This can be used inside renderer.Edited the answer.

Comment: When I use your example, then in the console I get the warning [W] XTemplate evaluation exception: this.getStore (...). IsLoad is not a function
And the field itself ceases to be displayed as all the fields following it.

Comment: the method is "isLoaded()", edited the answer. Any failure in render function will not update dom with that object hence there is a display failure.

Comment: Did as you advised me, but as before, each index_record value is -1. I edited my question